# Fluent NHibernate: map list of abstract class with table per concrete class (union-subclass)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having a problem with the following scenario.

My class structure is as follows:

```
public class Owner
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class PoweredVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public virtual string EngineType { get; set; }
}

public class Car : PoweredVehicle
{
    public virtual int Doors { get; set; }
}

public class Truck : PoweredVehicle
{
    public virtual long MaxLoad { get; set; }
}

public class Bicycle : Vehicle
{
    public virtual int FrameSize { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent mappings:

```
public class OwnerMap : ClassMap<Owner>
{
    public OwnerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Vehicles);
    }
}

public class VehicleMap : ClassMap<Vehicle>
{
    public VehicleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("10");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();
    }
}

public class PoweredVehicleMap : SubclassMap<PoweredVehicle>
{
    public PoweredVehicleMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.EngineType);
        Abstract();
    }
}

public class CarMap : SubclassMap<Car>
{
    public CarMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Doors);
    }
}

public class TruckMap : SubclassMap<Truck>
{
    public TruckMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.MaxLoad);
    }
}

public class BicycleMap : SubclassMap<Bicycle>
{
    public BicycleMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.FrameSize);
    }
}
```

I insert a Car and a Bicycle. When I try to insert an Owner with a list of Vehicle objects (with a Car and a Bicycle), I get the following error:

> Exception: NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert
>   collection:
>   [NHibernateTest.Owner.Vehicles#8ace95bc-ad80-46d7-94c7-a11f012b67c6][SQL:
>   UPDATE "Vehicle" SET Owner_id = @p0 WHERE Id = @p1] --->
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQLite error

Since I setup table per concrete class, why is NHibernate trying to update a non-existing table, which is representing the base class? Is this type of mapping not supported for this scenario?

Also, when I change from HasMany to HasManyToMany, this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the only choice is `Inverse()` mapping. This means that the concrete Vehicle (Car, Bicycle) must care about the persistence of the relationship.

To enable this, extend the `Vehicle` class with new property:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{ 
  ..
  // new owner independent navigation property
  public virtual Guid OwnerId { get; set; } 
}
```

and extend mapping of the Vehicle

```
public VehicleMap()
{  
  ..
  Map(x => x.OwnerId).Column("Owner_id);
}
```

and finally invert persistence responsibility. Not the owner, but the collection item will care about correct `Owner_id` column changes (when concrete `Vehicle` insert/update is invoked).

(more about inverse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454445/1679310)

```
public OwnerMap()
{
  ..
  HasMany(x => x.Vehicles)
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.All();
}
```

When `Vehicle` is added into `Owner`'s collection, its `OwnerId` must be also assigned:

```
owner.Vehicles.Add(car);
car.OwnerId = owner.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. It also works by adding the Owner object to the Vehicle object, and use a References() in VehicleMap. Then NHibernate automatically creates the Owner_id column in each of the concrete class tables.