# NHibernate Definitive Cascade application guide

Tags: c#, nhibernate, cascade

Are there any internet resources that have a definitive guide to all of the cascade settings for NHibernate that will include examples of the class structure, HBM and the implications of actions with each of the cascade settings for all of the relationships with NH.

Also it would be helpful if there were examples for common associations to be done in the most correct manner such as setting up a states table that you will never end up cascade deleting a state, or that deleting an object that has a CreatedBy User property will never end up deleting the User in a cascade etc.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The following is adapted from the Java Hibernate reference http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive for NHiberate 3.0 (ie the current svn trunk).

For each basic operation of the NHibernate Session - including Persist(), Merge(), SaveOrUpdate(), Delete(), Lock(), Refresh(), Evict(), Replicate() - there is a corresponding cascade style. Respectively, the cascade styles are named persist, merge, save-update, delete, lock, refresh, evict, replicate. The cascade style for Save() and Update() is save-update; for SaveAndUpdateCopy() it is merge; and for PersistOnFlush() it is persist. And remove is an alias for delete.

If you want an operation to be cascaded along an association, you must indicate that in the mapping document. For example:

```
<one-to-one name="person" cascade="persist"/>
```

Cascade styles my be combined:

```
<one-to-one name="person" cascade="persist,delete,lock"/>
```

You can use cascade="all" to specify that all operations should be cascaded along the association. The default cascade="none" specifies that no operations are to be cascaded.

A special cascade style, delete-orphan, applies only to one-to-many associations, and indicates that the Delete() operation should be applied to any child object that is removed from the association. And all-delete-orphan is the same as all,delete-orphan.

Recommendations:

- It does not usually make sense to enable cascade on a <many-to-one> or <many-to-many> association. Cascade is often useful for <one-to-one> and <one-to-many> associations.
- If the child object's lifespan is bounded by the lifespan of the parent object, make it a life cycle object by specifying cascade="all-delete-orphan".
- Otherwise, you might not need cascade at all. But if you think that you will often be working with the parent and children together in the same transaction, and you want to save yourself some typing, consider using cascade="persist,merge,save-update".

Mapping an association (either a single valued association, or a collection) with cascade="all" marks the association as a parent/child style relationship where save/update/delete of the parent results in save/update/delete of the child or children. A child which becomes unreferenced by its parent is not automatically deleted, except in the case of a <one-to-many> association mapped with cascade="delete-orphan". The precise semantics of cascading operations for a parent/child relationship are as follows:

- If a parent is passed to Persist(), all children are passed to Persist()
- If a parent is passed to Merge(), all children are passed to Merge()
- If a parent is passed to Save(), Update() or SaveOrUpdate(), all children are passed to SaveOrUpdate()
- If a transient or detached child becomes referenced by a persistent parent, it is passed to SaveOrUpdate()
- If a parent is deleted, all children are passed to Delete()
- If a child is dereferenced by a persistent parent, nothing special happens - the application should explicitly delete the child if necessary - unless cascade="delete-orphan", in which case the "orphaned" child is deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer explains this in details with HBM files. This answer covers the same with Mapping By Code. They are almost same; just mapped to their HBM strings.

Article form [Ayende](https://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update) explains it well:

> - none - do not do any cascades, let the users handles them by themselves.
> - save-update - when the object is saved/updated, check the associations and save/update any object that require it (including save/update the associations in many-to-many scenario).
> - delete - when the object is deleted, delete all the objects in the association.
> - delete-orphan - when the object is deleted, delete all the objects in the association. In addition to that, when an object is removed from the association and not associated with another object (orphaned), also delete it.
> - all - when an object is save/update/delete, check the associations and save/update/delete all the objects found.
> - all-delete-orphan - when an object is save/update/delete, check the associations and save/update/delete all the objects found. In additional to that, when an object is removed from the association and not associated with another object (orphaned), also delete it.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14438564/5779732) question explains few inner implementations of `Cascade`.

> ```
> [Flags]
> public enum Cascade
> {
>     None = 0,
>     Persist = 2,
>     Refresh = 4,
>     Merge = 8,
>     Remove = 16,
>     Detach = 32,
>     ReAttach = 64,
>     DeleteOrphans = 128,
>     All = 256,
> }
> private static IEnumerable<string> CascadeDefinitions(this Cascade source)
> {
>     if (source.Has(Cascade.All))
>     {
>         yield return "all";
>     }
>     if (source.Has(Cascade.Persist))
>     {
>         yield return "save-update, persist";
>     }
>     if (source.Has(Cascade.Refresh))
>     {
>         yield return "refresh";
>     }
>     if (source.Has(Cascade.Merge))
>     {
>         yield return "merge";
>     }
>     if (source.Has(Cascade.Remove))
>     {
>         yield return "delete";
>     }
>     if (source.Has(Cascade.Detach))
>     {
>         yield return "evict";
>     }
>     if (source.Has(Cascade.ReAttach))
>     {
>         yield return "lock";
>     }
>     if (source.Has(Cascade.DeleteOrphans))
>     {
>         yield return "delete-orphan";
>     }
> }
> ```

Please note that `Cascade.All` does not include `Cascade.DeleteOrphans`. In that case, you may need to include it using `Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans`.

Alternatively, you can use `Include` extension method `Cascade.All.Include(Cascade.DeleteOrphans)`.

In combination with `Cascade`, you may need to look into [`Inverse`](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/example-parentchild.html) as well; it specifies the owner of the association. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/713637/5779732) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951546/5779732) answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This might be obvious advice but I would suggest browsing old post made by [Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/default.aspx). A quick [search](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=nhibernate+cascade+site%3Aayende.com&aq=f&aqi=&oq=) for NHibernate and cascade on his site revealed a few interesting posts. They might, however, be a bit too scarce for your needs.

Even though it is not a internet resource per se, I would also recommend [NHibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/kuate/). It addresses cascades in some depth in chapter 3, 4 and 6. The book targets NHibernate 1.2. I do believe, though, that there will be a new edition of the book targeting the 3.0 release of NHibernate; it might be worth keeping an eye on.

As much as I would have liked to see a definitive guide to cascades I have not seen one. Maybe you could summarize some of the blog posts out there discussing cascades with your own post on your own blog.

Comment: I unfortunately was starting to believe this was the case however it's good to know about that in NHibernate in Action. I have so much blogging to do and so little time.

Comment: Definitely neither I have found an official documentation for Nhibernate 3 with mapping by code, etc. I think thats one of the downsides for NHibernate: is too complex to not have an updated doc

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any "definitive" guide, but the best resource I know is a blog post from Ayende, who is one of the definitive gurus in NHibernate:

[NHibernate Cascades: the different between all, all-delete-orphans and save-update](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/NHibernateCascadesTheDifferentBetweenAllAlldeleteorphansAndSaveupdate.aspx)

For me, I actually only use `cascade="none"` and `cascade="all"`. `all-delete-orphan` is sometimes an option. Everything else is suspicious. For instance, why should I implicitly create an instance because it is referenced, when it lives longer then the containing object? For me, there are only two situations: either the object is a dependent or independent.