# NHibernate: Cascading saves to children does not insert

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a bidirectional association like this:

```
public class Parent
{
  public int ParentId {get; set;}
  ...other properties
  public IEnumerable<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
  public int ChildId {get; set;}
  ...other properties
  public Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

The fluent mappings are as follows:

*Parent mapping*

```
Id(x => x.ParentId, "PARENT_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
.. other mappings
HasMany(x => x.Children).Cascade.All().KeyColumn("PARENT_ID");
```

*Child mapping*

```
Id(x => x.ChildId, "CHILD_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
.. other mappings
References(x => x.Parent).Column("PARENT_ID").Cascade.None();
```

When I execute code like this:

```
Parent parent = new Parent{ ..set some properties... };
parent.Children = new[] { new Child{ ..set some properties.. };
session.Save(parent);
```

I get a foreign key constraint violation because NHibernate is not setting the `PARENT_ID` column of the child record to the new ID when it attempts to insert the child.

Clearly I have requested cascading in the mapping for `Parent`. NHibernate is trying to save the child, but why is the ID not being set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make two changes.

1. You need `.Inverse()` on the `HasMany(x => x.Children)`.  See [my answer explaining inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951546/221708) for more information.
2. You also need to add `child.Parent = parent;` to the code that saves the entities.

In your case, the two relationships are conflicting with one another.  `parent.Children` contains `child`, which means that NHibernate should persist `Child.PARENT_ID` as the parent's Id, but `child.Parent` is null, meaning that NHibernate should persist `Child.PARENT_ID` as null.  Apparently `child.Parent` won.  Actually, what's more likely is that they both won.  NHibernate was probably executing two queries similar to these...

```
/* This is what child.Parent says we should save.
   This query will fail because PARENT_ID is NOT NULL. */
insert into Child (CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID) values (@childId, null);

/* This is what parent.Children says we should save. */
update Child set PARENT_ID = @parentId where CHILD_ID = @childId;
```

If you make the two changes I recommend above, NHibernate will be able to save this correctly, like so:

```
insert into Child (CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID) values (@childId, @parentId);
```

Comment: So I need to set both sides of the relationship before saving?

Comment: You at least need to set the non-inverse side of the relationship: `child.Parent`.  If `parent.Children` is inverse, then adding `child` to `parent.Children` is optional, but it's a good idea in order to keep your model consistent.  Another route would be to get rid of the `child.Parent` property altogether (you cannot make a `many-to-one` inverse), and leave the `HasMany(x => x.Children)` as non-inverse.  Whichever route you choose, you *must* set the value on the non-inverse relationship.

Comment: How would you drop child.Parent property and make the mapping in hibernate.config?