# NHibernate mapping by code (Loquacious) - Cascade options

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping, cascade

I have a question on Cascade enum options behavior when using NHibernate Mapping By Code.

Enum has following options:

```
[Flags]
public enum Cascade
{
    None = 0,
    Persist = 2,
    Refresh = 4,
    Merge = 8,
    Remove = 16,
    Detach = 32,
    ReAttach = 64,
    DeleteOrphans = 128,
    All = 256,
}
```

They are intended to be used like bit flag combinations (as far as I get it).

I've looked thru NHibernate documentation, and the following cascade options for XML mappings are defined there: [Lifecycles and object graphs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-graphs)

Can anyone describe cascade options from new Nhibernate mapping by code? Half of them are self describing, other half is not.

Comment: which are not self describing?

Comment: I'm not sure. Persist = Save-Update, Refresh? Merge? Remove=Delete, Detach=? ReAttach=? DeleteOrphans=delete-orphan, All=all.

Comment: I agree, this enum is a mess, `All` should really include all of the bitwise flags...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From `src\NHibernate\Mapping\ByCode\Impl\CascadeConverter.cs`

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> CascadeDefinitions(this Cascade source)
    {
        if (source.Has(Cascade.All))
        {
            yield return "all";
        }
        if (source.Has(Cascade.Persist))
        {
            yield return "save-update, persist";
        }
        if (source.Has(Cascade.Refresh))
        {
            yield return "refresh";
        }
        if (source.Has(Cascade.Merge))
        {
            yield return "merge";
        }
        if (source.Has(Cascade.Remove))
        {
            yield return "delete";
        }
        if (source.Has(Cascade.Detach))
        {
            yield return "evict";
        }
        if (source.Has(Cascade.ReAttach))
        {
            yield return "lock";
        }
        if (source.Has(Cascade.DeleteOrphans))
        {
            yield return "delete-orphan";
        }
    }
```

Note: `all` cascades all except of `delete-orphan`.

Answer (score 7):

- **None**: nothing cascades
- **Persist = ISession.SaveOrUpdate**
- **Refresh = ISession.Refresh**: loads the db state of the object into memory and updates its properties
- **Merge = ISession.Merge**: loads the object with the same Id from db and updates its properties with the properties of the given instance. returns the loaded object
- **Remove = ISession.Delete**: delete the given instance in db and detach from session
- **Detach = ISession.Evict**: removes the object from the session/change tracking
- **ReAttach = ISession.Lock(LockMode.None)**: reattach the given unmodified instance with the session
- **DeleteOrphans**: delete associated objects which are not referenced by the parent
- **All**:  all of the obove **except DeleteOrphans (thx to @Stefan Steinegger)**