# Nhibernate collections .Child entities not saved

Tags: asp.net-core, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, asp.net-core-2.2

Using

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
>   Version:   2.2.300
>   Commit:    73efd5bd87

and

> Nhibernate 5.2.5

Have the following entities

```
public class Customer : Entity {
    public Customer() {
        Initialize();
    }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string LegalName { get; set; }
    public virtual string VATCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    private void Initialize() {
        Sites = new List<Site>();
    }
}

public class Site : Entity {
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

with the following mappers

```
internal class CustomerConfiguration : ClassMapping<Customer> {
    public CustomerConfiguration() {
        Table( TableNames.CustomersTable );

        Id( x => x.EntityID, im => {
            im.Column( "CustomerID" );
            im.Generator( Generators.Identity );
        } );
        [... code omitted for brevity ...]
        Set<Site>( property => property.Sites,
            collection => {
                collection.Fetch( CollectionFetchMode.Join );
                collection.Lazy( CollectionLazy.Lazy );
                collection.Cascade( Cascade.Persist.Include( Cascade.DeleteOrphans ) );
                collection.Inverse( true );
                collection.Key( keyMapping => {
                    keyMapping.Column( "CustomerID" );
                } );
            },
            mapping => {
                mapping.OneToMany( relationalMapping => {
                    relationalMapping.Class( typeof( Site ) );
                } );
            } );
    }
}

internal class SiteConfiguration : ClassMapping<Site> {
    public SiteConfiguration() {
        Table( TableNames.SitesTable );

        Id( x => x.EntityID, im => {
            im.Column( "SiteID" );
            im.Generator( Generators.Identity );
        } );
        [... code omitted for brevity ...]
        ManyToOne( x => x.Customer, mm => {
            mm.Column( "CustomerID" );
            mm.NotNullable( true );
        } );
    }
}
```

I guess this mapping is not correct because if I do something like

```
using ( var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession() ) {
    var customer = new Customer() {
        Name = $"Customer 1",
        LegalName = $"Customer 1 LLC",
        VATCode = "xxxxxxxxx",
        Created = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    customer.Sites.Add( new Site() {
        Address = $"Address Customer 1",
        City = $"City Customer 1",
        Country = $"Country Customer 1",
        Customer = customer
    } );
    session.Save( customer );
}
```

I get the following exception

> Unhandled Exception: NHibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: Nhibernate.ConsoleApp.Entities.Site, Entity: [Site 0]

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

Actually the problem was  on a different area. it was because of the presence of two registered Listeners (`IDeleteEventListener` and `IUpdateEventListener`). Whenever I add those Update and delete does not work. However I was able to discover the problem thanks to [Roman Artiukhin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9667775/roman-artiukhin) comment

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502986/transientobjectexception-when-using-cascade-all

Comment: @Alexander I did read all the referenced post but unless I did not got the difference, In my case there is no composite ID in place. Both tables are using surrogate keys as database identities columns. I have updated the question to add the mapping IDs. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception is [telling](http://www.joaopauloseixas.com/howtodoit.net/?p=1695#operation_0) that the root entity `Customer` is holding the reference to other (`Site`) entity which is transient entity. That is why, root entity cannot be persisted.

> Scenario 1: No cascade options were configured.
>   In this case the child or referenced objects must be saved first.

```
using ( var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession() ) {
    var customer = new Customer() {
        Name = $"Customer 1",
        LegalName = $"Customer 1 LLC",
        VATCode = "xxxxxxxxx",
        Created = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    Site site = new Site() {
        Address = $"Address Customer 1",
        City = $"City Customer 1",
        Country = $"Country Customer 1",
        Customer = customer
    }
    customer.Sites.Add(site);
    session.Save( customer );//<--Save the master
    session.Save( site );//<--Save the site
    ...
    ...
    ...
    session.Flush();//<--You are calling this somewhere in your code
}
```

This should work.

> Scenario 2: Cascade options were not configured for all INPUT; UPDATE or DELETE operations.
>   In this case the configuration must be changed or  child or referenced objects must be saved first.

You have already:

- set `collection.Inverse( true );`
- added both [`DeleteOrphans | Persist`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14460204/5779732) values for [`Cascade`](https://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update) through extension method `Include`.

so this is not a problem.

> Scenario3: Related transient objects where instantiated and associated to the persitent object but no save operation is to be performed on those objects.
>   In this case the trainsient objects must be detached from the current session through the command:
>   `ISession.Evict(obj)`

Instead of `Evict`, you can call the `Save` to attach those objects explicitly as mentioned above.

For more insight, have a look at [documentation](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance) which explains various strategies.

Comment: You are completely right on your  suggestion. The problem was related to a listener registration. Please have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that collection is not your problem. It seems you have `Site` entity somewhere else exposed (for instance many-to-one `customer.LastSite` property or something like this). And cascade logic stumbles upon this not yet saved `Site` property before collection is saved. So you have to make sure that other `Site` properties are also have `Cascade.Persist` mapping

Comment: Actually this is not the right answer but thanks to this I was able to find the error which was exactly in a listener registration. Whenever I add a listener for `PostInsert` events, the listener is called when I do `Session.Create`. But if I add a listener for `PostUpdate` or `PostDelete` something strange happens: (1) the listener is never called when I do `Session.Update` or `Session.Delete` and (2) `Update` and `Delete` methods of `ISession` stops working. Please have a look at my edit.