# Fluent NHibernate Many to one mapping

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent

I am new to Hibernate world. It may be a silly question, but I am not able to solve it. I am testing many to One relationship of tables and trying to insert record. I have a Department table and Employee table. Employee and Dept has many to One relationship here. I am using Fluent NHibernate to add records. All codes below. Pls help

**SQL Code**

```
create table Dept (
    Id int primary key identity,
    DeptName varchar(20),
    DeptLocation varchar(20)
);

create table Employee (
    Id int primary key identity,
    EmpName varchar(20),
    EmpAge int,
    DeptId int references Dept(Id)
);
```

**Class Files**

```
public partial class Dept
{
    public virtual System.String DeptLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual System.String DeptName { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Int32 Id { get; private  set; }
    public virtual IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public virtual System.Int32 DeptId { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Int32 EmpAge { get; set; }
    public virtual System.String EmpName { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Int32 Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual Project.Model.Dept Dept { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping Files**

```
public class DeptMapping : ClassMap<Dept>   
{
    public DeptMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.DeptName);
        Map(x => x.DeptLocation);
        HasMany(x => x.Employees).Inverse().Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class EmployeeMapping : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.EmpName);
        Map(x => x.EmpAge);
        Map(x => x.DeptId);
        References(x => x.Dept).Cascade.None();
    }
}
```

My Code to add

```
        try
        {
            Dept dept = new Dept();
            dept.DeptLocation = "Austin";
            dept.DeptName = "Store";

            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.EmpName = "Ron";
            emp.EmpAge = 30;

            IList<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
            empList.Add(emp);
            dept.Employees = empList;
            emp.Dept = dept;

            IRepository<Dept> rDept = new Repository<Dept>();
            rDept.SaveOrUpdate(dept);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Here i am getting error as

> InnerException = {"Invalid column name 'Dept_id'."}
>   Message = "could not insert: [Project.Model.Employee][SQL: INSERT INTO [Employee] (EmpName, EmpAge, DeptId, Dept_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]"

Comment: Please check this link. Its very important mapping set up. http://thanigai.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-one-mapping-problem-with-insertfalse/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mattias' answer is almost right, but ForeignKey is used for schema generation. Try the below mapping instead. Also, you have the Employees collection mapped with CascadeAll. This will delete employee records if you delete a department, which is probably not desirable.

```
public class DeptMapping : ClassMap<Dept>
    { 
        public DeptMapping() 
        {
            Id(x => x.Id); 
            Map(x => x.DeptName); 
            Map(x => x.DeptLocation); 
            HasMany(x => x.Employees).KeyColumn("DeptId").Inverse().Cascade.All(); 
        } 
    }

public class EmployeeMapping : ClassMap<Employee>
{ 
    public EmployeeMapping() 
    { 
        Id(x => x.Id); 
        Map(x => x.EmpName); 
        Map(x => x.EmpAge); 
        Map(x => x.DeptId); 
        References(x => x.Dept, "DeptId").Cascade.None(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Jamie,  Thanks for the correction, I am able to insert record to Dept table. But it is not inserting records to Employee table. Looks like my coding to call SaveOrUpdate part has some mistake.I am like almost there, but not finally.

Comment: The line `dept.Employees = empList;`, changes the collection reference. You need to add the employee to the collection through `dept.Employees.Add(emp);`.

Comment: I replaced dept.Employees= empList with dept.Employees.Add(emp) , it is giving Object reference not set instance of an object. This is correct as the EmployeeColleciton is null. The employee is a IList<Employee> collection, it needs to be set first before adding items to it.So it will not work. Second thing, how collection reference is changed with it ?

Comment: You should initialize the collection in Dept's constructor: `Employees = new List<Employee>()`. In response to the second question, NHibernate provides its own collection implementation for IList, so when you assigned `deptEmployees = empList` the reference was changed from NHibernate's list to yours.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I implemented as you said. created a constructor to Employees. Also added another method to Dept class as AddEmployees. I am sending the code part again. Still I am not able to add record to Employee table. It is adding perfectly to Dept table.

Comment: Now I am able to insert the record to employee. I need to add Employee after adding the Dept. It maintained the same foreign key values.I feel it is bit weird. The department should take the whole path to insert. I don't know if it s by design or need to change some property. The code is below. Pls give your suggesiton.
 IRepository<Dept> rDept = new Repository<Dept>();
                rDept.SaveOrUpdate(dept);

                IRepository<Employee> rEmp = new Repository<Employee>();
                rEmp.SaveOrUpdate(emp );

Comment: Boss, I got the answer. I have made one mistake by making cascade.None() for dept.I changed it to Casecade.SaveUpdate(). It worked fine foe me. Thanks a lot for guiding me.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: Oh god! Why is ManyToOne suddenly called "References"? I want to slap Fluent Nhibernate authors for wasting hours of my time.

Comment: Why is Inverse() still needed? this just seems like internal implementation detail for the hardcore. Should this really be necessary?

Comment: Inverse is needed, here's a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713637/inverse-attribute-in-nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (as the error message tells you) that you don't have a column named "Dept_id". Your column name is instead "DeptId". The default conventions of fluent nhibernate is that the name should be with the underscore. To solve this you can ether change the name of the column in your database or you can override the convention in your mapping file to tell it to use your column name instead. That can be done in this way:

```
//EmployeeMapping
References(x => x.Dept).ForeignKey("DeptId").Cascade.None();

//DeptMapping
HasMany(x => x.Employees).KeyColumn("DeptId").Inverse() .Cascade.All();
```

Comment: I Made the changes  as you mentioned. I am still getting the same error.
public DeptMapping()
  {
   Id(x => x.Id);
   Map(x => x.DeptName);
   Map(x => x.DeptLocation);
            HasMany(x => x.Employees)
                .KeyColumn("DeptId")
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.All();
               
  }

public EmployeeMapping()
  {
   Id(x => x.Id);
   Map(x => x.EmpName);
   Map(x => x.EmpAge);
   Map(x => x.DeptId);
   References(x => x.Dept)
                .ForeignKey("DeptId")
                .Cascade.None();
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
[Serializable] 
public partial class Dept   
{       
    public virtual System.String DeptLocation { get; set; }

    public virtual System.String DeptName { get; set; }

    public virtual System.Int32 Id { get; private  set; }   

    //public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Dept()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();      
    }

    public virtual void AddEmployees(Employee employee)
    {
        employee.Dept = this;
        Employees.Add(employee);       
    } 
}
```

Employee Class

```
public partial class Employee
{
    //public virtual System.Int32 DeptId { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Int32 EmpAge { get; set; }
    public virtual System.String EmpName { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Int32 Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual Project.Model.Dept  Dept { get; set; }
}
```

The Code to call the method

```
try
{
    Dept dept = new Dept();
    dept.DeptLocation = "Austin";
    dept.DeptName = "Store";

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.EmpName = "Ron";
    emp.EmpAge = 30;


    dept.AddEmployees(emp); 


    IRepository<Dept> rDept = new Repository<Dept>();
    rDept.Add(dept);
}
```