# FluentNHibernate on a Oracle database, nullable foreignkey (Classic issue?)

Tags: oracle, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys, rights

Im in a bit of a jam.

**Problem**

NHibernate forces me to make a foreignkey column nullable, which is a very bad idea for our database and quite ugly.

Is there a work around for this?

**Situation**

I have the following maps (names changed for simplicity):

```
public class BillMap : SequenceGeneratedIdEntityMap<Bill>
{
   public BillMap()
   {
           Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native("BILL_SEQ");
           ... (maps) ...
           HasMany<Expense>(f => f.Expense)
            .Schema("ACCOUNT")
            .Table("EXPENSE")
            .KeyColumn("BILL")
            .Cascade.All();
   }
}

public class ExpenseMap : SequenceGeneratedIdEntityMap<Expense>
{
   public ExpenseMap ()
   {
      Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native("EXPENSE_SEQ");
      ... (maps) ...
   }
}
```

Using these maps I get the following from NHibernate when saving an instance of Bill:

```
select ACCOUNT.BILL_SEQ.nextval from dual
select ACCOUNT.EXPENSE_SEQ.nextval from dual

command 0:INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.BILL(...)
command 0:INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.EXPENSE(...)
command 0:UPDATE UPDATE.EXPENSE SET BILL = X WHERE ...
```

Notice 2 things here:

1. *All id's are requested from the sequences **BEFORE** the inserts.*
2. *The foreignkey is not updated until **AFTER** the expense has been inserted.*

This forces me to make the column nullable AND to allow updates on the table.

*Ideally the update statement should not be necessary and handled some deep dark place inside NHB :).*

This could be solved by making a bidirectional reference, but that would destroy my model :/.

I do believe this a returning issue for me (never found a good solution before). Are there anyone who knows of workaround?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

By setting `.Inverse()` on your `HasMany<Expense>` call, NHibernate will be aware of which side is the 'parent' object. I believe that will swap the order of the inserts.

For more information:

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started#Mappings

[Inverse Attribute in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713637/inverse-attribute-in-nhibernate)

Comment: That it would, but that would also break my model unfortunatly :/.

Comment: With that (and not calling the repositories and saving independently), perhaps ask on the NHibernate users group (http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers). If they can come up with the NH XML code, we can find a way to get it working in FNH (or submit a patch at https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate).