# fluent nhibernate mapping with not null foreign key (HasMany)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following mapping in nhibernate.
When I call `Session.Merge(myparent)` I get the an error on the insert indicating that `NULL` cannot be inserted into the foreign key (`ParentItemId`) column.

How can I adjust the mapping so that the parent key is inserted on insert. If I make the foreign key nullable this mapping works, but two separate statements are issued to the database.

This relationship is a one to many without a reference back to the parent on the child class.

The child class has no parent property.

The child is dependent on the parent.

```
HasMany(map => map.Children).Table("ChilrenTable")
   .KeyColumn("ParentItemId") // this is not nullable.
   .Cascade
   .AllDeleteOrphan();
```

**example update**

```
// entity here is the parent instance, which contains the list
// of children.
using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    entity = Session.Merge(entity); // this line causes the problem.
    Session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
    Session.Flush();
    tx.Commit();
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Inverse Attribute in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713637/inverse-attribute-in-nhibernate)

```
HasMany(map => map.Children).Table("ChilrenTable")
   .KeyColumn("ParentId") // this is not nullable.
   .Inverse()  // <--- This is the key here
   .Cascade
   .AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Comment: I tried this, but the merge is still failing. Perhaps it has something to do with the merge. I am merging changes back to the database from posted web data that is being sent to a WCF service. The WCF service is merging and updating the data. It still attempts to insert a null value, and then subsequently updates the foreign key value.

Comment: Reading a little further, it would seem that perhaps inverse only works with bi-directional relationships. In my case the relationship is not bi-directional. The parent owns the child items, but the child items have no parent property and hence no nhibernate mapping to the parent.

Comment: @Jim Maybe you should make it a bidirectional relationship.

Comment: Hi Cole, that's what I am beginning to think as well. The reason I have not is that the serialization over WCF can be an issue with circular relationships. I think I will use bi directional relationships and mark all the data contracts as IsReference = true.