# Will NHibernate SaveOrUpdate be able to work thru entity's related objects as well?

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I have an NHibernate entity that has 2 relationships of many to many.

Suppose I have a detached version of this entity, will SaveOrUpdate be able to decide Saving or Updating thru the related objects as well?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how relationship is configured.

The main things that come to mind are cascading and whether it is [inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713637/inverse-attribute-in-nhibernate) or not.

If you want things to automatically cascade (~work thru) then just set that in you hbm collection association node

```
cascade="all"
```

There are [more cascading options](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update) worth reading and understanding