# What do inverse and readonly attributes do in NHibernate napping do?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

While I am working a  project I have seen this line of NHibernate mapping

```
HasMany(entity => entity.Tasks).KeyColumn("APPLICATION_ID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().ReadOnly().Inverse();
```

it is the first time for me I see some one using the inverse and readonly attributes so please could anyone explain them to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713637/inverse-attribute-in-nhibernate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse Attribute in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713637/inverse-attribute-in-nhibernate)

Comment: The rational behind `inverse` is further documented in [NHibernate reference](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-bidirectional), it is an essential mechanism for bidirectional associations. And `Readonly` is a shorthand for `mutable="false"`, as explained [here](http://notherdev.blogspot.fr/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html). See [ask], you are supposed to do some research before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a detailed description of inverse [here](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/search/label/inverse)

TLDR; from the link

- Inverse is a boolean attribute that can be put on the collection
  mappings, regardless of collection's role (i.e. within one-to-many,
  many-to-many etc.), and on join mapping.
- We can't put inverse on other relation types, like many-to-one or one-to-one.
- By default, inverse is set to false.
- Inverse makes little sense for unidirectional relationships, it is to be used only for bidirectional ones.
- General recommendation is to use inverse="true" on exactly one side of each bidirectional relationship.
- When we don't set inverse, NHProf will complain about superfluous updates.

And this [link](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-property.html) for Readonly

TLDR;

The only difference apart from different naming for some properties and Property vs. Map name itself is the ReadOnly method available in FNH. **It is just a shortcut for setting both .Not.Insert() and .Not.Update().**

Comment: There is no `update`or `insert` attributes on collections mapping. For collections, Fluent `ReadOnly` is a shorthand for `mutable="false"`.